# A palindromic number reads the same both ways. Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers

Tags: java

This my solution to ProjectEuler's problem 4
"A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99." Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

When I run this program it does not display anything in the console and I am not sure why because I don't see a problem with my code.

```
public class Problem4 
{
    static boolean end = false;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int multiplier = 999;
        int product = 0;
        while(end = false )
        {
            product = multiplier * 999;
            isPalindrome(product);
            multiplier--;
        }
    }
    public static Boolean isPalindrome(int number)
    {   
        int b = (Integer.valueOf(number).toString().length() - 1);
        char[] storage = new    char[Integer.valueOf(number).toString().length()];
        char[] reverse = new char[Integer.valueOf(number).toString().length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < Integer.valueOf(number).toString().length(); i++)
        {
            storage[i] = (Integer.valueOf(number).toString().charAt(i));
        }
        for(int a = 0; a < Integer.valueOf(number).toString().length(); a++)
        {
            reverse[a] = storage[b];
            b--;
        }
        String compare = "";
        for(int x = 0; x < Integer.valueOf(number).toString().length(); x++)
        {
            compare += reverse[x];
        }
        if (compare.equals(Integer.valueOf(number).toString()))
        {
            System.out.println(number);
            end = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is easy:

`while (end = false)`

should be in your intentions:

`while (end == false)` or even better `while (!end)`

Otherwise it means that you are assigning `false` to end, and then evaluating `end`, which is always `false`.

For reference, in future I'd recommend you to try using the debugger for such cases.